# How to select with css specific id only if have specific class on same div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So this is situation, fist code show class when nav is on bottom...

```
<div id="navigation" class="attached-to-bottom">
 <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

this show when my navigation stay sticket to top after i scroll down (with jquery etc etc), but i need change navigation id height to be different when i triger class "attached-to-top") Can i do that with CSS only or?

```
 <div id="navigation" class="attached-to-top">
     <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply don't use a space between them.

```
#navigation.attached-to-top { height: 100px; }
```

More information on [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: In CSS 3 it's called ["sequence of simple selectors"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#sequence).

Comment: im nooob :S i mean i try that but i use wrong height element etc etc... sorry